# Affine sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider an arithmetic sequence with first term $a$ and common difference $d$. The sum of the first four terms is 42 and the sixth term is 28.

An affine sequence is a sequence defined as $u_{m+1}=ru_{m}+s$, where $s$ is the common ratio and $s$ is the common difference.

The second, fourth and eighth terms of the arithmetic sequence are the second, third and fourth term of the affine sequence.

(a) Show that $u_{m+1}=r^{m}u_{1}+s\left(\frac{r^m-1}{r-1}\right)$

(b) Show that the $m^{th}$ term of the affine sequence equals the $2^{m-1}$th term of the arithmetic sequence.

**Solution (a)**

I believe I managed to do (a) as below:

$$u_2=ru_1+s$$
$$u_3=r^2u_2+s=r^2u_1+rs+s$$
$$u_4=r^3u_3+s=r^3u_1+r^2s+rs+s$$
hence
$$u_{m+1}=r^mu_1+s\left(r^{m-1}+r^{m-2}+...+1\right)=u_{m+1}=r^{m}u_{1}+s\left(\frac{r^m-1}{r-1}\right)$$

**Solution (b)**

I am able to solve for $a$ and $d$ from the arithmetic sequence and they are $a=3$ and $d=5$.

I am, however, totally lost on how to prove (b). Any hints on what is the first step that I should take? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you formalize your observations for part (a) into a rigorous solution, perhaps using induction? As for (b), what is "the arithmetic sequence"?

Comment: @GregMartin Would that be possible using mathematical induction? I will try. I have included more information into the question and I hope that would help in solving (b).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for (b)**

Given that you've already found the arithmetic sequence, the condition that the second, third and fourth terms of the affine sequence are equal to the second, fourth of eighth of the arithmetic sequence gives you three equations for the three unknowns $\ u_1,r\ $ and $\ s\ $ of the affine sequence.  Although these equations are non-linear, it's not hard to reduce them to a pair of linear equations for $\ r\ $ and $\ s\ $, which you should find easy to solve.

> \begin{align}a_n&=3+5(n-1)\\a_2=8=u_2&=ru_1+s\\a_4=18=u_3&=r^2u_1+s(1+r)\\&=r(8-s)+s+rs\\&=8r+s\\a_8=38=u_4&=r^3u_1+s(1+r+r^2)\\&=r(18-s-rs)+s+rs+r^2s\\&=18r+s\\r&=2\\s&=2\\u_1&=3\\u_m&=5\times2^{m-1}-2\\a_{2^{m-1}}&=3+5(2^{m-1}-1)\end{align}